# Writing Async(Or async like) Client Socket Code in Java

Tags: java, sockets, asynchronous

I am writing a socket client for interacting with a network service. Currently because I want to support async reading and writing I am threading both the output stream and the input stream of one socket, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. I have taken a look at Java NIO and was not very impressed, and I also looked at Mina, but was wondering if anyone had any better ideas.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The technique I used for asynchronous communication was to use an ExecutorService. In my example below, the service would execute a FutureTask that would wait for the next line. In the meantime, the server could continue executing other tasks and periodically poll the reader to see if a result was received yet.

For writing you could implement a similar FutureTask.

*Note: You need not extend the functionality of an existing Stream/Reader/Writer like I did. This was just the source code that I had handy*

```
 public class SocketStringReader extends BufferedReader {
    /**
     * Internal buffer used for asynchronous reads
     */
    private HashMap<String, String> buf = null;
    /**
     * Waiting status used for asynchronous reads
     */
    private boolean waiting = false;
    /**
     * Shared ExecutorService for asynchronous reads
     */
    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    /**
     * Constructor here to pacify Java
     * @param in The InputStream to be used as the underlying stream
     */
    public SocketStringReader(InputStream in) {
        super(new InputStreamReader(in));
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> readHashMap() throws IOException,
    ClassNotFoundException {
        if (buf != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> resp = new HashMap<String, String>(buf);
            buf = null;
            return resp;
        }
        return stringToHashMap(this.readLine());
    }

    /**
     * Parses a string and converts it to a HashMap
     * @param map A String object of the format "{key=value, key=value, ...}" 
     * that is parsed into a HashMap
     * @return The parsed HashMap
     */
    public static HashMap<String, String> stringToHashMap(String map) {
        // take the string apart
        String[] split = map.split("[={},]");
        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 1; i < split.length; i += 2) {
            result.put(split[i].trim(), split[i + 1].trim());
        }
        logger.debug("new incoming HashMap: " + result.toString());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the availability of the input stream
     * @return The number HashMap objects in the internal buffer
     */
    public int getAvailable() throws IOException {
        return (buf == null) ? 0 : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> readHashMapAsync() throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        //Check internal buffer
        if (buf != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>(buf);
            buf = null;
            return temp;
        } else {
            //Do future crap? or nothing perhaps...
            if (!waiting) {
                waiting = true;
                FutureTask<HashMap<String, String>> future = new FutureTask<HashMap<String, String>>(
                        new Callable<HashMap<String, String>>() {
                            @Override
                            public HashMap<String, String> call() throws Exception {
                                buf = stringToHashMap(readLine());
                                logger.debug("Read object with sessionid: " + buf.get("sessionid"));
                                waiting = false;
                                return null;
                            }
                        });
                executor.execute(future);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from Mina and NIO there are a couple of other libraries (all generally built on top of NIO)

- [xSocket](http://xsocket.sourceforge.net/)
- [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty)
- [Grizzly](https://grizzly.dev.java.net/)
- Also JDK 7 is adding support for [Async IO](http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousChannel.html)